# ElasticSearch funtion_score like query in Solr

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr

I am migrating from ES to Solr. I had used `function_score` query in ES searching for the same in Solr now but couldn't find any. Does Solr support anything like `function_score` [query-dsl-function-score-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Function queries enable you to generate a relevancy score using the actual value of one or more numeric fields. Function queries are supported by the `DisMax`, `Extended DisMax`, and `standard` query parsers.
>
> Function queries use `functions`. The functions can be a `constant` (numeric or string literal), a `field`, `another function` or a `parameter substitution` argument. **You can use these functions to modify the ranking of results for users**. These could be used to change the ranking of results based on a user's location, or some other calculation.

**Yes.** Solr supports function queries. You can find the solr official documentation [Function Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) for more detailed information.